# Building a rails Model using initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have a model like so:

```
class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :phrase, :emotion, :category
end
```

This model corresponds to it's appropriate table. Every time I want to create a new `Phrase`, I run this code in a controller:

```
Phrase.where(:phrase => values['phrase']).first_or_create do |phrase|
  phrase.emotion = values['emotion']
  phrase.category = values['category']
end
```

I feel like I should be using the initialize method on my model, or perhaps creating a new method on my model to build them up. The above method seems pretty bad, especially when I start building models with 20+ attributes.

Is there a best/better practice around building models? Should the above controller code actually live in the model somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def create
    @phrase = Phrase.new(params[:phrase])
  end
```

or if you are using strong parameters

```
def create
  @phrase = Phrase.new(phrase_params)
end

private

  def phrase_params
    params.require(:phrase).permit(:phrase, :emotion, :category)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your model allows for mass assignment of those attributes via `attr_accessible` you can just pass a hash to `new`:

```
Phrase.new(values)
```

You can also use `find_or_create_by` with a hash of options:

```
Phrase.find_or_create_by_phrase(values[:phrase], values)
```